# Magento - configurable - does not update price when selecting an option on frontend

Tags: magento

I have created a configurable product, with 4 associated simple products

The attribute that the configuration is using is size.

I have created 4 simple products, each with a different size and price

All of these sizes are displaying on the configurable product in the frontend, but the problem is, that when i select a sie option, the price does not get updated.

Neither does when selecting an option and adding to the cart. It seems to keep the price of the configurable product whatever option I select.

I have done the usual, refreshed cache, re-indexed, several times. I've even cleared browser cache.

When selecting an option, I get no JS error in Firebug, nothing at all to tell me the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

I'm using 1.6.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behavior of Magento.
You can try to use Simple Configurable Product module (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html), but there is own problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did find that extension and it seems to work for me. It's a shame that this isn't part of magento out of the box

Answer (score 1):

When you associate the simple products with the configurable product, there is a place on the page to specify the difference in price for each option. If you don't set that, then the price won't update correctly.

Comment: But if associated product price is changed (mostly by import function) difference for option in configurable product must be changed too manually. If admin does that not - old price will be used (configurable product price + old diference)

Answer (score 1):

We developed an extension for fixed final prices for simple configurable products. It also works on version 1.6 and 1.7. And what is great is that it also works with multiple attributes.

Please check here: http://magento.modulabs.com/mage_en/magento-fixes-prices-simple-configurable-products.html

There is also demo so you can see it in action (backend and frontend).

Answer (score 0):

Magento is not setup to pull the price from a simple product if you are looking at the parent configurable.  You can however use the 'super product attributes' inside of "associated products" to add or remove from the configurable price shown.

The field "price" is shown as a value to add or remove, do not enter the full price of the item, only the difference you wish to see.

This can be more tedious on sites with larger inventories but definitely does the trick!

[Simple Product Price for Configurables](https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple)