# product prices not updating in configurable products

Tags: magento

I am looking at creating a configurable product that has various prices.

Having looked at this, it seems that when you select an option, that has another price, the price field of the `product options` section does not update.

I have provided an image below:
[Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/844/conf2.png)

You can see that I have selected a product option, `Oxygen`, which is £273. I was expecting the product price of the option to update to match this, but it doesn't.

Under the `Associated Products` section, I have added a fixed price for the associated products, but this still does not update the price.

I cannot believe that this isn't available out-of-the-box with Magento.

Has anyone ever noticed this before?

I have found [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506349/magento-configurable-does-not-update-price-when-selecting-an-option-on-front)

Which seems to suggest that it has been noticed before.

Does Simple Configurable Products fix this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCP will solve your problem - it takes the price from the child product. Unfortunately, this will not work too well if you are also using Custom Product Options with price differentials.

Depending on the complexity of your products you may want to go with normal Magento and a script to work out what the price variants are for the super attribute options. The array for the super attribute price options can be iterated over, master and child products checked against the attribute(s) that change, e.g. colours, and a new attribute array written out. It is a bit of code you will have to write yourself, but here is an article that covers the basics:

http://www.ayasoftware.com/content/magento-update-fly-super-product-attributes-configuration

Comment: Hi. I only have 2 configurable products,each have 3 product options. I have had a look at SCP, but it didn't change the product price. i.e the one in the image (the product option price remained at £273) no matter what the actual price of the option was.

Comment: You can see what I mean [here](http://cbiss-ecomm.bluelogic.co.uk/gas-detection/portable-gas-detectors/gasbadger-pro-3.html) - changing the option does not change the price of the product. It remains at Price From: £273

Answer (score 0):

worse, scp does not allow the customer to edit the choice. My Client insisted he could edit his choice so we had to develop for this using the JSON encoded script on the product view page instead.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $jason = $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>
<?php $uJason = json_decode($jason); ?>
<?php
if ($_product->getMsrp() > 0) {
    $uJason->productMsrp = sprintf("%01.2f", $_product->getMsrp());
}
$jason = json_encode($uJason);
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $jason ?>);
</script>
```

I think we had to change the code elsewhere but the above change allowed the msrp to update as well as the price.